# Unable to run Xdebug in PhpStorm, connections are refused - likely due to port 9000 not being open or not being forwarded

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, putty, portforwarding

I'm trying to debug my PHP code running on a remote server using PhpStorm's Xdebug feature. A few weeks ago I was able to do this on another computer, but I no longer have that computer.  I reinstalled and configured PhpStorm and can run SFTP and SSH with the remote server on the new computer.  I tried using PuTTY, and was successfully able to use it to SSH Tunnel between the two computers and run Xdebug.  But it wasn't a 'good' as the way I was able to do this on the other computer, which didn't need PuTTY.

I believe that the problem has to do with setting up Port-9000 forwarding.  I added a rule for this to my BitDefender BOX2 for the local computer I develop on, but I still get refused.  The tech at BitDefender thought that there may be another port that needs to be opened/forwarded in addition to port 9000.

Because the PuTTY method works on the new computer, I'm confused.  Why does this work with PuTTY, but not directly with PhpStorm (without the help of PuTTY)?

Answer (score 2):

Xdebug only needs port 9000, so that is the only port that PhpStorm will listen on, and Xdebug needs to connect **to**. I don't know BitDefender, but perhaps you only allowed outgoing connections, and not the incoming ones that you should allow?

Are the two machines on the same network, or is your machine behind a NAT network to the outside world, where your remote machine lives? In that case, you probably can't get around using your SSH tunnel with PuTTY.

You don't mention any settings, but it is worthwhile to check what shows up in the xdebug log file (when configured with `xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log` on  your **remote** machine). It will show what Xdebug tries to connect to, and whether (and sometimes even *why*) the connection failed.

Comment: Thanks.  Only port 9000, great.  BitDefender does allow outgoing and ingoing connections.  The development computer and the remote server are not on the same network.  The remote server is definitely outside of my local network, and I'm not connecting to it using VPN.  I don't think I'm using a NAT network, how would I know?  My remote server is in Virginia, and my local network is in California.  The log simply says that the connection is rejected.

Comment: @HowardBrown So you need to configure your router (or whatever you have there) to allow incoming connection on that TCP 9000 port to reach your computer. Xdebug is the one that connects to IDE/editor so you need to config your network to allow such incoming connection. If you do not want to do that (regardless of the reason) or do not know how, use SSH tunnel -- for your network it's an outgoing connection (Xdebug here connects using SSH port forwarding)